# "Cross Cubic variation" of Two Brownian Motions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider two independent 1-dimensional Brownian motions $W_{t},B_{t}$, with an equidistant partition of the interval $[0,T]$, and $n\Delta≡T$

How to calculate the expression below? Can we rewrite the limit of the summation as an Ito integral?
$$ S=\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta} 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(W_{(i+1)\Delta}-W_{i\Delta})^{2}⋅(B_{(i+1)\Delta}-B_{i\Delta}) $$

NOTE:

I have done many numerical experiments by Monte-Carlo simulation, I find on interval $[0,1]$ the summation converge to a random variable (I guess it is normal) with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.73 (approximately) by the function "normfit()" in MATLAB.

However, I can not guess the final expression of $S$ because of the "wierd" 1.73 .

Comment: Do you want to compute $S$ explicitly or do you only need its distribution?

Comment: I want to compute S explicitly.                                To some extent,... I believe it can transform to a stochastic integral

Comment: Also, knowledge of the distribution of $S$ is fine, but I think , by plenty of histograms from samples I do on MATLAB , it is normal ditrbution with mean $0$

Comment: My two cents: 1) It's not too much of a problem to compute the variance of $S$ (provided that we know that the limit exists, say in $L^2$). 2) I think it's possible to show that $(S_n-B_T)^2$ converges in $L^2$ to some constant $c$; here $S_n$ denotes the $n$-th partial sum. However, this does unfortunately not allow to identify $S$.

Comment: This question was posted at mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337400/%d0%a1ross-%d1%81ubic-variation-of-two-brownian-motions-and-interpretation-of-the-simula) $1$ hour after it was asked here and received two answers there.